# Append class instances into a list at instantiation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following problem:

I have classes like:

```
class Sequence1(AbstractSequence):
    def Run(self):
        #Something to do

    def Help(self):
        #Help

class Sequence2(AbstractSequence):
    def Run(self):
        #Something to do

class Sequence3(AbstractSequence):
    def Run(self):
        #Something to do

class Test1(AbstractTest):
    def Body(self):
        Sequence1()
        Sequence2()
        Sequence3()

    def ReportGeneration():
        #Do some report generation

    def CheckPreconditon():
        #Do some report generation

class Test2(AbstractTest):
    def Body(self):
        Sequence2()
        Sequence3()

    def ReportGeneration():
        #Do some report generation

    def CheckPreconditon():
        #Do some report generation

class RunTests():
    SequencesToDo = []

    def runTests(self):
        Test1()
        Test2()
```

I want to append the instances of the Sequences in Test1 and Test2 to the SequencesToDo list in RunTests class, but I don't really know how can I solve it. The aim of this is that a tester should build only the Tests using the Sequences (they are already written), and then I should store them (the sequences) in the list, from which I can run the whole test, or any other functions inside the Sequences (i.e.: Help, or Precondition check).

I don't know if I'm on the right path, is it a valid way to get through the problem, or should find another way for it?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but "class" are first class citizen. You can use them like ... say ... functions: `self.tests = (Test1, Test2); for t in self.tests: t().run()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding exactly what you are trying to accomplish but you should be able to just append Test1() and Test2() to SequencesToDo.  You can then run the Sequences by doing something like this:

`for sequence in SequencesToDo:
    sequence`

I don't really see the point in this though since you can run them just how you have it.  Perhaps you want to store the results of the instances being run?

As far as your question, it's never a bad idea to separate your tests from your actual code.  Look into unittests.  The unittest module may provide you with the exact thing you need.